# FFmpeg creates empty palette, for better quality GIF conversion

Tags: android, ffmpeg

FFmpeg creates empty palette, for better quality GIF conversion

I have referred to

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#palettegen-1

https://superuser.com/a/556031/724432

but it creates an empty pallete file

I am trying it on android

the command used is

```
{"-y", "-i", j, "-ss", 10, "-t",3,"-vf","fps=15,scale=300:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen", palette};
```

and the error that is shown is

```
ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
  configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/sdcard0/try/Videos/2018-03-13-15-47-29.mp4.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2018-03-13 15:47:33
  Duration: 00:00:03.39, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 615 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x540, 637 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 22.95 fps, 60 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-13 15:47:33
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 12 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-13 15:47:33
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Output #0, image2, to '/storage/sdcard0/try/Gifs//2018-03-16-11-36-48.png':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: png, rgba, 16x16 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbn, 10 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-13 15:47:33
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
      encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 png
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> png (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
[Parsed_palettegen_2 @ 0xac96ed80] 255(+1) colors generated out of 3594 colors; ratio=0.070952
[Parsed_palettegen_2 @ 0xac96ed80] Dupped color: FF5F5F5F
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
```

any help would be useful

Answer (score 1):

Remove `"-ss", 10, "-t",3,`. Your input is only 3 seconds long.